# SVG won't stay inside <div> in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

Here's a good one: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekStocks/9YS8F/)

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
#divResearch {
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(((100% - 70px) * .05) + 40px);
    left: 3%;
    width: 94%;
    height: calc((100% - 70px) * .75);
    background-color: darkgreen;
}
```

If you look at the fiddle above using Chrome 31 (or even IE 11 - can you believe it?!) the SVG graph (gray background) stays inside the container (div with green background) as you **move the Result window resize handles around**.  The SVG has been told to maintain its aspect ratio; you can see excess green in either the width or height depending how you've resized the window.

*This does not work in FF 26*.

In FF 26 as you resize the width the SVG height just keeps getting larger and is never constrained by the div.  Is this a FF bug or poor CSS3 on my part?  This code passes W3C validation (fwiw).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem on Firefox 26.0

Comment: @user2314737 I can. As the window gets narrower, the svg gets smaller than the div, as it gets wider, the svg gets bigger and leaves the div.

Comment: @Alexander Kosubek Correct, I've tested this on 2 different machines before posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `width="100%"` and `height="100%"` to the svg-tag helps.

regarding the w3c.org documentation it should be 100% if not set:
"If the attribute is not specified, the effect is as if a value of '100%' were specified."

So it seems that FF26 has a problem with the default values for the svg element

Comment: Your answer works nicely in all browsers. As the desire is to allow the SVG to scale to the div, it seemed incorrect to declare a width and height on the SVG element itself.  The percentage method does not hurt, but as you eluded, it should not be necessary.  FF bug.  Which seems to be happening with more and more regularity  :-(

Comment: This answer is misleading as Firefox's behaviour is actually correct per http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewportSpace The default width attribute which is indeed 100% does **not** establish the viewport's width.

Comment: @GeekStocks There's no FF bug here.

Comment: @Robert - completely disagree.  The answer states FF has a problem with defaults and this is very well demonstrated here in the fiddle.  Are you saying Chrome and IE are buggy because they display correctly?  lol Rhetorical.  FF does not implement the proper default; Chrome and IE do.

Comment: Please read the reference I supplied. Yes, Chrome and IE are buggy. The Chrome developers know this and are working on a fix for this issue, the IE developers don't talk about future versions of IE so I don't know when or if this will be fixed in IE.

Comment: @Robert: I don't understand your argumentation why the width should **not** establish the viewport's width. As you're refering to the w3c Viewports specification, please read the 2. paragraph: "The ‘width’ attribute on the outermost svg element establishes the viewport's width, unless the following conditions are met".<br/> So, that's exactly the opposite of your argumentation, or am I wrong?

Comment: All the conditions **are** met so the width does **not** establish the viewport width.

Comment: so i see this is still an issue in ff36, correct? what's the solution?